# How to embed related data in Django from models?

Tags: python, django, laravel, django-models, eager-loading

I've been working on Django since couple of days. I know how to get what I want in Laravel but I need help in Django.

Suppose I have two tables.
authors and books

books table contain:

```
id, name, author
```

authors table contain:

```
id, name
```

With Laravel, I can just add a function which gives relationship between books and authors and `Book::with('authors')` will give me all the data of books along with extra field `author` which contains detail of the author of the book. I don't know how to do this Eager Loading with Django.

If suppose I use 
`Book.objects.all()`

Then I would want all the books in an array. And in every item of book, there should be one object available which will give details about that author.
For example:

```
{
[
{
 id: 3
 name: "Name of book",
 author: {
  id: 7,
  name: "Author name"
 }
},
{
 id: 4
 name: "Name of other book",
 author: {
  id: 3,
  name: "Author of other book"
 }
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Base(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=100)

    def to_dict(self):
        rtn = {}
        c = self._meta._get_fields(reverse=False)
        for i in c:
            item = str(i).split('.')[2]
            if hasattr(self, item):
                rtn[item] = getattr(self, item)
        return rtn

class Books(Base):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name='authors')

    @classmethod
    def get_all_books(cls):
        l = []
        books = cls.objects.all()
        for book in books:
            book_dict = book.to_dict()
            book_dict['author'] = book.author.to_dict()
            l.append(book_dict)

        return {'result': l}

class Author(Base):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I edited y answer in this way all you have to do is just call

```
Book.get_all_books()
```

the result would be like this

```
{
'result': [
  {
    id: 3
    name: "Name of book",
    author: {
      id: 7,
      name: "Author name"
    }
  },
  {
    id: 4
    name: "Name of other book",
    author: {
      id: 3,
      name: "Author of other book"
    }
  }
]
```

}

Comment: Sorry, but looks like you understood something else. I've added more description in the question.